# Can we restore from backups which created from different OS?

Tags: marklogic

Is it supported/possible to restore database from backups,
which created from MarkLogic installed in different OS version?
or even different OS?
(e.g. -create backups from RHEL6, restore ML on RHEL7.
-create backups from CentOS, restore ML on Windows Server.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different OS version, yes (typically). Different OS, no.

If you need to backup/restore across OSes, use something like MLCP that exports the database to a universal archive format. Then you're still on the hook for handling database config, some of which can be handled with Configuration Manager. To migrate security and generally any other settings not handled by Configuration Manager, look into ml-gradle.

The documentation for backup/restore is in their developer documentation: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/backup_restore

> The backup files are platform specific--backups on a given platform should only be restored onto the same platform. This is true for both database and forest backups.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, do you know where these information written in official documentation or site?

Comment: Thank you so much!